# joining two table and show the attribute name instead of id

Tags: mysql

**choicelist table**

```
chl_element  chl_label    chl_dependent_value  chl_value
country      india                             IN
state        karnataka    IN                   KA
city         bangalore    KA                   BNG
```

**users Table**

```
elo_state  elo_country  elo_city
KA         IN           BNG
```

how can i join the two table and shows the `country` name that is india instead of `In` .....i don't want to use sub queries because while searching it will create problem

Comment: try a join statement and post it if you hit errors

Comment: please format this i am new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the users table with the choicelist table. Also you need to specify which attribute you are joining. For example if your users table contains the column username you could use this:

```
SELECT
  users.username,
  c1.chl_label AS country,
  c2.chl_label AS state,
  c3.chl_label AS city
FROM
  users LEFT JOIN choicelist c1
  ON users.elo_country=c1.chl_value AND c1.chl_element = 'country'
  LEFT JOIN choicelist c2
  ON users.elo_state=c2.chl_value AND c2.chl_element = 'state'
  LEFT JOIN choicelist c3
  ON users.elo_cITY=c3.chl_value AND c3.chl_element = 'city'
```

here I'm joining the users table with choicelist multiple times, with multiple aliases (c1 c2 c3).